# Inject script file in Page source - Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, phantomjs

The HTML page has the script as below:

```
<script src="/_res/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=5At4BVuSsWGYDY9lb87tCvy" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On `onResourceRecevied` function, i can see above script downloaded successful.
Then i inject them to `page` :

```
page.injectJs('/_res/js/jquery.js').then(async function(res) {
          console.log("injectJs")
        page.injectJs('/WebResource.axd?d=5At4BVuSsWGYDY9lb87tCvy').then(async function(res) {
            console.log("injectJs")
        })
})
```

The console logged "injectJs" but i can not call the any function on that script files.
I inject wrong path file or i have to use `includeJs` instead?

Thanks

=====================

**UPDATE**

I would like to update more detail for my issue:

The HTML code for the page which i want to do something on it:

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=abc" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a id=btnNext" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("btnNext", "", true, ""))">
   <span><span>Next</span></span>
```

I would like to trigger action on the button `btnNext` with function `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("btnNext", "", true, ""))` from the script embedded in HTML (from `/WebResource.axd?d=abc`)

Here is my code:

```
page.injectJs('./WebResource.axd?d=abc')
        .then(async function(res) {
            console.log("injectJs")

            //Next button click
            await page.evaluate(function () {
               WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("btnNext", "", true, ""))
            });
})
```

The result is not expected, my code is not trigger that function.

Comment: Why do you inject them if the page already has them?

Comment: because i can not call these javascript function in my code.

Comment: But you can. If some scripts are requested by the page itself, you don't need to inject/include them. Please update the questions with how you've tried to use the libs in your code.

Comment: @Vaviloff: i've updated my question and code. Please take a look. thanks

Comment: PhantomJS does not support Promises and Async/Await functions. Or are you using it via node.js library?

Comment: @Vaviloff: yes, i used phantom-nod library for nodeJS

Comment: I'd suggest that you 1) mention that in the question 2) try to trigger-click that #btnNext